# How to assert failing require statement in Foundry

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

In my contract A I have a function foo which has a require statement

```
contract A {
  bool public requirement;
  
  function foo() public {
     require(requirement, "State not set correctly for continuation");
     ...
  }
}
```

Now I want to test this with Foundry

```
contract ATest is Test {
   function testFoo() public {
        // executing function with some account
        vm.prank(someAddress);
        A.foo(); // <- this will fail
    }
}
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy once found the documentation for that. It works for both, require and revert.

```
contract ATest is Test {
       function testFoo() public {
            // executing function with some account
            vm.prank(someAddress);
            vm.expectRevert(bytes("State not set correctly for continuation")); // <- add this
            A.foo(); // <- this will fail
        }
    }
```

For documentation go here: https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/expect-revert